# Testlink (1.9.12) automation integration error

Tags: testlink

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to my testlink server after a test run:

> br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: Failed to read server's response: http

here is the string i use to create the testlink connection :

> `http://usrname:test@http://{ip_server}/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php`

Anyone could know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax) is invalid format!

```
http://usrname:test@{ip_server}/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php
```

The extra "http://" in the middle does not belong!